# How to correctly use setInterval for multiple functions being called repeatedly in React Native

Tags: react-native, timer, setinterval, use-effect

I am building a simple app in React Native that aims to flash different colors on the screen at certain time intervals. My implementation is as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    var blinkOnValue;
    var blinkOffValue;

    function blinkOn() {
        const colorAndWord = getRandomColor(colorArray);
        setBackground(colorAndWord.color);
    }

    function blinkOff() {
        setBackground('#F3F3F3');
    }

    if (strobeStart) {
        if (on) {
            blinkOnValue = setInterval(() => {
                blinkOn();
                setOn(false);
            }, info.length * 1000);
        } else {
            blinkOffValue = setInterval(() => {
                blinkOff();
                setOn(true);
            }, info.delay * 1000);
        }
    }
    return () => {
        on ? clearInterval(blinkOnValue) : clearInterval(blinkOffValue);
    };
}, [colorArray, info.delay, info.length, on, strobeStart]);
```

The blinkOn function sets the background a certain color and the blinkOff function sets the background a default light gray-ish color. These functions should alternate back and forth, blinking on and off at different intervals. For example, if info.length is 2 and info.delay is 0.5, then the color should flash on for 2 seconds and then the screen should be light gray for 0.5 seconds and repeat. However, the duration of both of the blinkOn and blinkOff are happening for the same amount of time, no matter what the two values are. Sometimes it uses the value from info.length, and sometimes it uses the value from info.delay which is also quite strange.

I think it has something to do with components mounting and unmounting correctly but honestly I am quite lost. If anyone has any advice on how to make this code consistently work where it flashes appropriately I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to time your events just right, I suggest using a single timer and computing the blink state from the current system time.

```
var oldState = true;

function blink() {
    var ms = new Date().getTime(); 
    var t = ms % (info.delay + info.length);  
    var state = (t < info.length ? true : false);
    if (state == oldState) return;
    if (state) {
        blinkOn();
    }
    else
    {
        blinkOff();
    }
    oldState = state;
}
```

Now set a short timer to check the time and update the blink state as needed:

```
setInterval( () => blink(), 100 );
```

Comment: Thank you! What a smart way to approach the problem. Works perfectly!